# Regular Expression for Strings with even number of b's followed by the letter c followed by an odd number of a's

Tags: regex, regular-language

I have managed to figure out the regular expression for **even number of b's** and **odd number of a's** through `(bb|aa|(ba|ab)(bb|aa)*(ab|ba))*(a|(ba|ab)(aa|bb)*b)`

What if I need the following sequence:

1. Even number of b's
2. Followed by the letter 'C'
3. Followed by odd number of a's

any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (zero is an even number):

```
^(bb)*ca(aa)*$
```

Answer (score 0):

Expression for even no. of b's: `(bb)*`
Expression for odd no. of a's: `(aa)*a`
So the overall regular expression is:
`(bb)*c(aa)*a`